# Visual Studio 2022 dont open "Choose Toolbox Items" window

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, toolbox

I just installed Visual Studio Community 2022 on a new computer with windows 11.

It presents the following problem: When I go to the toolbox and right-click and go to "Choose Items...", it was to open a window called "Choose Toolbox Items", but nothing happens, it shows nothing anywere indicating loading, it's like I don't have clicked.
When using it on an old computer with windows 10 it worked correctly.

I've already tried to use repair, I've tried to reinstall, I found some tips from old versions of visual studio saying it could be such software but as it's a clean install of windows 11, there's nothing besides windows and drivers installed yet.

Would windows 11 be the problem?

.net sdk is installed too.

Answer (score 1):

In my case for some reason it was the visual studio language.

It was in my native language because it took the language of windows, to make it easier to find the right search terms I changed it to English, so it started working.

I tested it a few times, and really, when I went back to my language, it stopped working, and when I went back to English it worked.

This bug burned some of my neurons and I just didn't understand the logic of it being the language's fault.